# Reference a python function in another directory

Tags: python, function

I have a python file `main.py` which is the driver of my GUI program and a folder `games` both inside the same folder. I want to refer the driver function in a file `games\TicTacToe.py` which is declared in `main.py`. How can I do it?

Here is my file structure

```
Project
|-games
|   |-TicTacToe.py
|   |-Snake_Game.py
|-main.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))`  to be able to access functions in the script from the parent directory. Then you can do `import main`

Answer (score 1):

If it works for you move the
main.py
to the games folder
then put this at the start of the code:
`import main`
and every time you need to use one of its functions do
main.functionName()

or if you only need to use one function then do this code:
`from main import FunctionName`
then when you use it you can dothis:
`FunctionName()`

Comment: So the only viable option is to change the structure of the file?